# Table of Contents for Appendicies

Tags: latex, tableofcontents

I want to create a second table of content for my appendicies. I try to do it with minitoc but it doesn't work. Maybe anybody has another idea or a solution with minitoc.

The example:

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[left=4cm,right=3cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[page,toc,titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listfigurename
\listoftables
\chapter{test}
\section{One}
\section{Two}
\section{Three}
\section{Four}
\chapter{test2}
\section{Test2-One}

\begin{appendices}
    
    %% New TOC for content in the appendix
    
    \section{Append PDF}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

The result I want to have:

Table of content:
1 test
1.1 One
1.2 Two
1.3 Three
1.4 Four
2 test2
2.1 Test2-One

Appendicies
A.1 Append PDF

Thankyou for your help forward.

Best regards
Christian